# MVC Html custom Helper cut spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I wrote helper

```
  public static class TestHelper
  {
    public static string Test(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        var writer = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(), string.Empty);
        //writer.InnerWriter.NewLine = string.Empty;
        //writer.NewLine = string.Empty;
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Ul);  //<ul>
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        {
          RenderRow(helper, writer, i);
        }
        writer.RenderEndTag();                        //</ul>
        return writer.InnerWriter.ToString();
    }

    private static void RenderRow(HtmlHelper helper, HtmlTextWriter writer, int i)
    {
      writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Li);
      writer.Write(i);
      writer.RenderEndTag();
    }
  }
```

and use it the same way:

```
@Html.Test()
```

but in result I see html tags in browser. The problem is a space before the first tag:

```
<ul> <li>0</li><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li> </ul>
```

there is a symbol with code 020h before "ul".
I tryed:

1) in the Test class:

```
return writer.InnerWriter.ToString().Trim();
```

2) in the cshtml file:

```
@Html.Test().Trim()
```

3) Tryed to change writer settings

```
writer.InnerWriter.NewLine = string.Empty;
writer.NewLine = string.Empty;
```

But all these without positive result (third step partly clean the code).
Is here any way to have html code without tabs, spaces, end of string etc?

Answer (score 1):

`Trim()` will only eliminate the leading and trailing spaces. Use `.Replace("  ", string.empty)` instead.